# Issues with bigdecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to calculate leaseRate which is a big decial, However I receive the following error:
`Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result`
I see that this is round issue, however I think that I solved this with `MathContext precision = new MathContext(2);`

I made a small example this issue:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MathContext precision = new MathContext(2);
    int mileage = 10;
    int duration = 20;
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("34234.34",precision);
    double interestRate = 4.57;
    BigDecimal bMileage = new BigDecimal(mileage, precision);
    BigDecimal bDuration = new BigDecimal(duration,precision);
    BigDecimal bInterestRate = new BigDecimal(interestRate,precision);
    BigDecimal leaseRate = ((((bMileage.divide(
        new BigDecimal(12,precision))).multiply(bDuration)).divide(
        price)).add(
        ((bInterestRate.divide(new BigDecimal(100,precision))).multiply(
            price)).divide(new BigDecimal(12,precision))));
    System.out.println(leaseRate);
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Generally speaking when you use `BigDecimal` for precise results, you should avoid having *any* `float` or `double` values of any kind in that code. You already create `price` correctly (using a String literal), I suggest you use the same approach for the interest rate and get rid of the `double.interestRate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `MathContext` as the second argument to each call to `divide`, e.g.

```java
bMileage.divide(new BigDecimal(12), precision)
```

Comment: See the full code working here: https://ideone.com/MuVh1v